# Error handling in a multi-threaded application

Tags: c, multithreading, error-handling, pthreads, mutex

Say a thread function looks like:

```
void *threadFunc(void *args)
{
    if(args == NULL)
    {
        /*
         * Let's assume that this case is a fatal error which
         * cannot be recovered from.
         */

        fprintf(stderr, "Yikes... demons avoided.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Code to do stuff

    return NULL;  // Return value does not matter
}
```

**Note:** My example here is just an analogy I crafted to closely resemble the real problem I'm facing.

<sub>PS: Don't worry, my error messages are more descriptive in reality.</sub>

---

The scenario I'm seeing is that this fatal error is detected by more than 1 thread *sometimes*. I've found that sometimes, when a thread detects this error and reaches the `fprintf`, it gets preempted by another thread which also detects the same error and also gets preempted when it reaches its `fprintf` and so on.

I'm just wondering how I can handle this particular case such that when one thread detects this fatal error, it shuts down the application immediately in a way such that other threads don't interfere with it while it is trying to shut the application down.

I'm thinking to surround the error detection in a mutex as follows:

```
void *threadFunc(void *args)
{
    lockMutex(mutex);
    if(args == NULL)
    {
        /*
         * Let's assume that this case is a fatal error which
         * cannot be recovered from.
         */

        fprintf(stderr, "Yikes... demons avoided.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    unlockMutex(mutex);

    // Code to do stuff

    return NULL;  // Return value does not matter
}
```

This does not seem very elegant to me because if a failure is detected, then the application will exit leaving the mutex locked. I know the OS is supposed to free all resources, but this still does not seem very nice to me.

Could you suggest another, possibly better way I can do this? Is my design itself broken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bool deadmanWalking = false;
mutex deathMutex = INIT....

void cleanup()
{
    lock(&deathMutex);

    if (deadmanWalking)
    {
        unlock(&deathMutex);
        return;
    }

    deadmanWalking = true;

    // cleanup code

    unlock(&deathMutex);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

//.........

    if(args == NULL)
    {
        cleanup();
        pthread_exit(...);
    }
```

Arguably the best solution is to return with an error indication from the error detecting thread(s) to whatever started them and let it orderly cancel the remainder of threads and cleanup rather than just dropping the bottom out from under them by exiting.

Comment: Hmm interesting. But this also has the same problem. All the threads *could* get preempted right after `unlock(&deathMutex)`. So all the threads would again detect this error condition. I think your final statement makes more sense. Let the refactor begin!

Comment: They could detect the error condition but all they will ever do is pthread_exit.  Only one thread is going to clean up and exit. But canceling is better if also more work.

Comment: That isn't exactly what I was going for. I wanted the first thread that detects the error to shut down the program then and there. As to why, I suspect that there's some other code that does not check for this error condition and thus, I'm observing some strange segfaults. But you're right, instead of making this code more convoluted, a refactor would be better (I'm already about 40% done with it anyway). Thanks!

Comment: 1+ for "*... orderly ...*"